# Diff command along with Grep gives "Binary file (standard input) matches"

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, grep

I am trying to use the diff command in conjugation with the grep command to find the difference between 2 files. In other words I have yesterday's file and today's file, I need to find the lines that are new in today's file i.e which were not there in yesterday's file.

I am using the below command to put my required output to the file 'diff.TXT':

```
diff  <(sed '1d' 'todayFile.txt' | sort ) <(sed '1d' yesterdayFile.txt | sort ) | grep "^<"  >> 'diff.TXT'
```

This worked fine until today it produced the 'diff.TXT' as :

```
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

This happened in my prod environment but it works in test environment.
So I tried to do some debugging on this by breaking up the command in test environment.

I broke my initial command into 2 parts :

```
diff  <(sed '1d' 'todayFile.txt' | sort ) <(sed '1d' yesterdayFile.txt | sort ) > temp.txt
grep "^<" temp.txt
```

And alas I get the same error in test environment now which I was getting in prod.

```
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

This seems very strange to me.

One strange thing in test environment that I noticed when trying by splitting the command is that, on doing `file -i temp.txt`, it gives binary.

Can someone please help out with this

Comment: Use `grep -I` to skip binary files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [man grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

> -a, --text
>
> Process a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the --binary-files=text option.
>
> --binary-files=TYPE
>
> If the first few bytes of a file indicate that the file contains binary data, assume that the file is of type TYPE. By default, TYPE is
> binary, and grep normally outputs either a one-line message saying
> that a binary file matches, or no message if there is no match. If
> TYPE is without-match, grep assumes that a binary file does not match;
> this is equivalent to the -I option. If TYPE is text, grep processes a
> binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to the -a option.
> Warning: grep --binary-files=text might output binary garbage, which
> can have nasty side effects if the output is a terminal and if the
> terminal driver interprets some of it as commands.

`grep` scans the file, and if it finds any unreadable characters, it assumes the file is in binary. Add `-a` switch to `grep` to make it treat the file a readable text. Most probably your input files contain some unreadable characters.

> diff  <(sed '1d' 'todayFile.txt' | sort ) <(sed '1d' yesterdayFile.txt | sort ) | grep "^<"

Wouldn't be `comm -13 <(...) <(...)` faster and simpler?

Comment: `when ... it does not work, but ... it does not work` How exactly does it differ? What does differ?

Comment: Any idea why the results differ in test when I split the original command. i.e when I use diff <(sed '1d' 'todayFile.txt' | sort ) <(sed '1d' yesterdayFile.txt | sort ) | grep "^<" it does work, but if I use diff <(sed '1d' 'todayFile.txt' | sort ) <(sed '1d' yesterdayFile.txt | sort ) > temp.txt, followed by grep "^<" temp.txt then it does not work. It seems the line diff <(sed '1d' 'todayFile.txt' | sort ) <(sed '1d' yesterdayFile.txt | sort ) > temp.txt is saving the file in binary format

Comment: Nee, it should be the same, must be a difference in the files or smth. Until you post the file content (the best in a unique format, ex. after `xxd -p`) others can't replicate the problem, so there's nothing for me to inspect. I can only say "it should work, it's really strange if it doesn't". In your post you said that both outputs are the same, tho.